# Canvas to ImageView problem in Android

Tags: android

I want to display Canvas contents on ImageView in android,

but ImageView displaying blank.

```
Bitmap imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

canvas.drawBitmap(imgBitmap, 0, 0, paint);

paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setAlpha(100);
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100, paint); // transparent black on image

imgView.draw(canvas);
```

what is the problem? and what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When [ImageView.draw()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) is called its actually putting the contents of the ImageView into the provided canvas, you have it logically backwards here. Instead use [Canvas(Bitmap)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) constructor instead (so your canvas will draw on to the bitmap) then [ImageView.setImageBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) with the same bitmap given to the canvas. You can use [Bitmap.createBitmap(int, int, Bitmap.Config)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29) to create the size of Bitmap you want. And remember if you have the canvas draw outside the Bitmap's bounds it is clipped.

Comment: Thanks for answer. `Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bimap.Config.ARGB_8888); Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); ... imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`